# Show that every nonnegative integer $n$ is of the form $n = \alpha\cdot 2^{b+1} + \gamma$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that for every nonnegative integers $n$ and $b$ we have $\alpha \geq 0$ and $0 \leq \gamma < 2^{b+1}$ such that $n = \alpha\cdot 2^{b+1} + \gamma$.

So let $n\geq 0$ be an integer.
If $n$ is a multiple of $2^{b+1}$, then $\alpha = \frac{n}{2^{b+1}}$ and $\gamma = 0$.

But if it is not, we have $\alpha\cdot 2^{b+1}<n<(\alpha+1)\cdot 2^{b+1} \Leftrightarrow \alpha < \frac{n}{2^{b+1}}<\alpha+1$.

I would now say we choose $\alpha = \lfloor \frac{n}{2^{b+1}}\rfloor. $
But how can I now prove the range where to choose $\gamma$ from?

Comment: $\alpha$ doesn't have to be a non-negative *integer*?

Comment: @peterwhy Yes it does, else $n$ would be negative.

Comment: I mean $\alpha$ doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: Hint: try subtracting rather than using the floor function.

Comment: @peterwhy But I want it that way. Then it's unique

Comment: Compare $$n = \left\lfloor\frac n{2^{b+1}}\right\rfloor 2^{b+1}+\gamma$$ with Euclidean division or division with remainder, then $\gamma$ is the (least non-negative) remainder.

Comment: The excess of variables clouds this, but this is standard partial division. For any integer $p$ and strictly positive integer $q$, there exist unique integers $m$ and $r$ such that $p = mq + r$ and $0 \le r < q$. The number $m$ is the partial quotient, and $r$ is the remainder. Here $p = n$ and $q = 2^{b+1} > 0$.

Comment: Compare $$\frac n{2^{b+1}} = \left\lfloor\frac n{2^{b+1}}\right\rfloor  +\frac\gamma{2^{b+1}}$$ with the properties or definition of the floor function, and check that $0\le \gamma/{2^{b+1}} < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply arithmetic: Let $\alpha$ be the largest nonnegativve integer such that $\alpha 2^{b+1} \le n$. [Indeed, there exists such an $\alpha$ as $0 \times 2^{b+1} \le n$.] Then $\alpha$ is *uniquely specified*, and the quantity $n-\alpha 2^{b+1}$ is nonnegative as the inequality $\alpha 2^{b+1} \le n$ holds. Furthermore, the inequality $n-\alpha 2^{b+1} < 2^{b+1}$ holds, lest the inequality $(\alpha+1)2^{b+1} \le n$ holds as well, which would contradict the definition of $\alpha$. So set $\gamma = n-\alpha 2^{b+1}$; then  $\gamma$ is *uniquely specified* as well. Furthermore, as observed above, $n=\alpha 2^{b+1} +\gamma$, with $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ uniquely specified, with $\alpha$ a nonnegative integer and $\gamma$ a nonnegative integer less than $2^{b+1}$.